# Force object to have at least one key ( Object.keys(o).length > 0 )

Tags: typescript, tsc, typescript3.0

Say I have this object

```
export interface Name {
   [key: string]: boolean
}

const v = <Name>{};
```

how do I prevent this from compiling? What I want to do is force `v` to have at least one property:

```
const v = <Name>{foo: true};
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible.  If you say more about your scenario, we might have more ideas.

Comment: You should add more details. It is not possible in the abstract, but possible in certain scenarios.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do this for a variable. To begin with you can't at the same time infer the type of a variable and add an annotation to it. And by default any annotation you add can't constrain the existence of at least one arbitrary property.

If you have a function, and you want to ensure a function parameter has at least one property, we can use a conditional type to generate something akin to a custom error:

```
function noEmpty<T>(o: T & (keyof T extends never ? "No empty object" : {})) {

}

noEmpty({}) // err Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type '{} & "No empty object"'.
noEmpty({ a: ""})
```

Comment: Looking forward to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317 It could make the solution cleaner

Comment: @Yozi yeah that would help, but it has been pushed back so i don't know when it will be available ..